# Date filter in mongoDB dynamic query

Tags: javascript, meteor

I found an answer that shows how to create dynamic query in MongoDB. Now I need to add a filter on the date less another date.

I wrote this code but it doesn't work:

```
query['scadenza'] = {
    '$lt': new Date(new Date().getTime() + (Session.get('scadenzaTra') * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
};
```

If I put an alert after the assignment I get a correct date value but I don't see ant row.

What is wrong?

Comment: Where does it fail? what is the error? Please give more information. I guess there is something wrong with `Session.get('scadenzaTra')` because without it it works (of course if the `scadenza` field is actually a date...)

Comment: If I put an alert after the assignment I get a correct date value but I don't see ant row.

Comment: I'd be pretty positive you meant `new Date().valueOf()`, for which you could also simply write `Date.now()`. You seem to want to add a *"number of days"* which is presumably contained in the returned value of `Session.get('scadenzaTra')` and therefore multiplying that to the number of milliseconds in a day. Therefore you want the milliseconds from the current time in order to make that valid. Not sure what purpose this serves, since this addition is always going to result in a "future date", unless of course the returned session variable is actually "negative".

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags. I'm editing your error information in the question already.

Answer (score -1):

```
$startDate = Carbon::createFromDate(2016, 9, 22);
    $endDate = Carbon::createFromDate(2016, 9, 24);
$users = User::where('created_at','>',$startDate)
   ->where('created_at','<',$endDate)->get();
```